# SQL Server shortcuts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 and I normally write queries in one line. I remember someone showing me a shortcut to format/view to move the code to multiple lines. I've tried searching for it but can't seem to find it. Its really bugging me. Its possible I was working with another version of SQL when I was shown this. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Hmmm . . . The <return> key works for me.

Comment: Are you talking about some auto formatting that fixes your one line queries? If so I only know of third party addins such as apex SQL refactor.

Comment: [Formatting T-SQL in SSMS 2012](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45051/formatting-t-sql-in-ssms-2012)

Comment: I think you mean something simple as Word wrap. The option is available in the options menu under text editor. I think there is no keyboard shortcut for it by default, but you may be able to define one.

Comment: My guess is that OP talks about to write sentence in Visual Studio. Place your beds.